# PHP Laravel - jQuery not working - ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I created a fresh Laravel project and added jquery file at:

```
rootproject/public/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js
```

Now in `welcome.blade.php`, in html header tag I am referencing it as:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And put an `alert()` message in document load function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert("my message");
});
```

But its not working. In console log it is showing error message:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Can anybody suggest how to fix it?

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<link href="{{ asset('/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

with:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are including JS file in CSS way:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

that's the issue. Replace it with:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}"></script>
```

every thing will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="<?php echo URL::to('/'); ?>/public/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Add script in this way

Comment: Please include some information as to why this is the correct answer. furthermore there are way more elegant ways to do this in laravel and your link does not work in the advertised laravel setup (since public should be the served root, so the link would be example.org/js/etc)